# Scaling the probability mass function

Tags: normal-distribution

I have produced a histogram of the frequency of observing some variable, call it $x$. I have then used the following equation:

$$f(x;\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

To estimate the value of the pmf at every observation point, which I then too plotted. This results in two 'bell curves'. However, I need to rescale my pmf so that it 'matches' the frequency plot. How does one actually find that scaling constant?

I have in my notes, that one should use:

$$f(x;\mu,\sigma)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

But how $c$ is found is never mentioned.

I had an idea of simply turning the frequency histogram into the probability one, so that I have for each observation frequency/total frequency and then rescaling the pmf so that the area under the curve is $1$. Not quire sure what to do next. And I do not think this would be the right way as I would then need to rescale back the pmf so that it matches that original frequency plot.

EDIT:
I got it. That idea was actually useful. That constant is such that the area under the two curves is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The function you gave is actually a PDF of Gaussian distribution:
$$f(x;\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

PMF is for discrete observations. In order to *scale* you have to integrate PDF within bounds of your bins. For instance you have the following bins: $(-\infty,-10],(-10,10],(10,\infty)$, then you have three PMF values, i.e. one for each bin like follows:
$$PMF_1=\int_{-\infty}^{-10}f(x;\mu,\sigma)dx$$ and so on for other two bins.

That's for theoretical PMF. If you're looking for observed probabilities then you must divide the observed frequencies by total number of observations. For instance, you got the following number of observations in the bins: 20, 65, 15. You observed probabilities would be: 0.2, 0.65 and 0.15.

Now you can compare them with theoretical (when $\mu,\sigma$ are somehow known in advance) or fitted (where $\hat\mu,\hat\sigma$ are estimated from data) PMF that you calculated the way I showed first.